# XML Layouting for a textview and 2 imageviews

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-xml

I need to make a layout with a single lined TextView and 2 ImageViews. They need to be in the following order: **TextView** | **ImageView1** | [*Remaining space*] | **ImageView2**

All this with the constraint that in case of the text overflow in the TextView the 1st ImageView gets pushed and sticks to the 2nd one and the overflowing text gets trimmed and shows up with an ellipsis. Something like this: **Trimmed TextView**... | **ImageView1** | **ImageView2**

For better clarity of the instances, here's an illustration:
[image]

How should the layouting be done for this particular use case?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

**Output1 :**

[image]

**Output2 :**

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_message"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Hello Mike bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla " />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tv_msg_time"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/done_all"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_message"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="end">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/job_like" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to formulate the answer; however empty space shows up between the tick and the heart. I would want that whenever the ellipsis is shown, the tick and the heart is rendered immediately one after the other.

Comment: Ok i will try for that.

Comment: @Sagar try my edited answer. Let me know if any another issue.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!